# Android Contacts intent only contains filename when opening uri

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, vcf-vcard

I try to write an app that works as an layer between my contacts and sms app.
So that I get an extra option for my app when sharing a conatct via vcard.
My application receives the intent allright.
I get the content:// uri by

```
Uri uri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

and I can get an AssetFileDescriptor with:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
```

no problem. likewise opening the file:

```
InputStream is = afd.createInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)afd.getDeclaredLength()];
is.read(buffer);
```

however this file only contains "[" and a hex string. I would think it should consider the actual vcard file?
because I did

```
buffer.toString();
```

instead of

```
new String(buffer);
```

which doesn't convert the utf-8 encoded bytes correctly, stupid stupid stupid 8 hour mistake....

Trying to open the uri with query()

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

gives me a cursor that contains one row
???, firstname lastname.vcf, null

where ??? is three numerals.

maybe someone else has use for reading this though.

Comment: So... What is the actual question?